# Should we use delete[] or delete on function that return allocated memory pointer?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, new-operator, delete-operator

Should i use delete[] or delete for Register() example below? We hit some memory leak issue and legacy code which is not allow to change the return type and input of the function. I understand that new[] should use delete[]. new should use delete. However for case below, which method is correct?

```
UINT Register(UINT regaddr, usb_dev_handle* current_handle)
{
    unsigned int val= 0;
    unsigned char* buffer = readregister(current_handle, char((regaddr >> 8) & 0x00FF), char(regaddr & 0x00FF));
    raddrvaluefinal = buffer[2] << 8 | buffer[3];

    delete buffer;
    return val;
}

unsigned char* readregister(usb_dev_handle *current_handle, char one, char two)
{
    unsigned char *buffer = new unsigned char[4];
    char cmd[2];
    cmd[0] = 'D';
    cmd[1] = 'B';
    int rv = 0;
    unsigned char bin_size[2];
    buffer[0] = one + 0x80;
    buffer[1] = two;
    buffer[2] = buffer[3] = 0;
    usb_bulk_write(current_handle, 0x02, cmd, 2, 500);
    bin_size[0] = (5 / 4) & 0x0FF;
    bin_size[1] = ((5 / 4) >> 8) & 0x0FF;
    rv = usb_bulk_write(current_handle, 0x01, (char*)bin_size, 2, 2000);
    unsigned int byteswrite += usb_bulk_write(current_handle, 0x04, (char*)buffer, 4, 2000);
    unsigned int bytesread += usb_bulk_read(current_handle, 0x86, (char*)buffer, 4, 2000);
    buffer[0] = one;
    buffer[1] = two;
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be aware that you are not using C language as you added in the tags, but C++. They are very different languages and should not be confused.

Comment: Looking at `unsigned char *buffer = new unsigned char[4]`, do you think that uses `new[]` or `new`?

Comment: One option would be to have a struct with 4 bytes, and return that by value. Then you wouldn't need any new  or delete at all.

Comment: *We hit some memory leak issue and legacy code* -- The person who originally wrote that code was either a poor programmer or wasn't aware to simply return a `struct` containing an array.  The `4` is a small constant value -- there is absolutely no need to be using `new[]` for a small, constant, number of items.  If it were a million items and that was constant, then that would be the justification to allocate dynamically, since you would want to use the free-store for that amount of memory.  But for a small constant, like `4`, that is lazy coding, to be honest with you, to use `new[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand that new[] should use delete[]. new should use delete.
>
> ```
> unsigned char *buffer = new unsigned char[4];
> ...
> delete buffer;
> ```

The program is wrong, and against your understanding. When a dynamic array is allocated dynamically with `new[]`, `delete[]` must be used to deallocate it. If you use `delete`, then the behaviour of the program is undefined.

---

You shouldn't use owning bare pointers in the first place, and in this case there doesn't even seem to be any need to use a dynamic array. I recommend following instead:

```
std::array<unsigned char, 4>
readregister(usb_dev_handle *current_handle, char one, char two)
{
    std::array<unsigned char, 4> buffer;
    // ...
    usb_bulk_write(current_handle, 0x04, reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer.data()), 4, 2000);
```

---

Sidenote: "new -> delete", "new[] -> delete[]" is a slight oversimplification. `delete[]` must be used if `new` is used to create an array:

```
using T = int[4];
int* ptr = new T;
delete[] ptr; // correct
```

Comment: Thank you all for the constructive feedback, this should solve my issue. Well Explained.